# Cannot read text file because of error

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, text-files

Currently in terminal running spark-shell (2.3.0) using Scala version 2.11.8 with Java (1.8.0_171).

Running programs such as

```
scala> val number = 5
number: Int = 5
```

works perfectly fine however, when I try to read from a textfile, I encounter this problem

```
scala> val textFile = spark.read.textFile("C:/Spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:428)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:233)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:691)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:730)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:700)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:180)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:114)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:385)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
  ... 86 more
```

Comment: I think its a permission issue at `The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------;` Use `hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /tmp` (Beware of excessive permissions!)

Comment: I tried the solution for that but it did not work for me, however I do apologize as I'm not necessarily sure how the two questions are different as I am fairly new to this.
EDIT: The problem was that I had two versions of java, one of 10.0.1 and another 1.8, even though the JAVA_HOME was set to 1.8, I believe it still ran 10.0.1 for some reason but I just had to uninstall it to fix the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the permissions for `/tmp/hive` to make it writable.

Try `chmod 777 /tmp/hive/` but bear in mind that it's almost certainly too permissive and you want to grant only the minimum permissions.